# How does model binding work to update

Tags: angularjs

This is probably a basic/fundamental question.

See this example
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_bind

Im wondering about how the expression

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p>{{name}}</p>
```

Is update on each keystroke into the text field.  Is this the case with binding in general using ng-model?  In other words, as soon as the model is updated, all the expressions that reference that variable or model will be updated also?

Comment: If the reference is in the same scope, it will be updated.

Comment: It's updated because the variable of ng-model is the subject of a *watch*, so technically no it doesn't update based on user input like a keystroke.  To understand ng-model is to understand scopes generally, here's a [nice read](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: @RamblinRose - thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the model will be updated as soon as the user types. `ng-model-options` allows you to change the default behavior of the input field's interaction with ng-model. You can change which event causes the model to get updated and several other options.

[angular docs on ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)